# UIWebView, embed youtube video

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

How to detect when play button, in embed youtube frame, pressed in UIWebView? Thanks.. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot even after implementing UIWebViewDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method. it allows you to run javaScript methods within webView. Call the method in webView didFinishLoading method found in the delegate class.

you must likely going to have to check if a HTML object exist inside the website using  document.getElementById(aHTMLTag);

that red play button in inside that div statement:

```
<div class="ytp-cued-icon html5-center-overlay html5-scalable-icon ytp-cued-icon-image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the simplest task, but you should implement [youtube's api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference). You'll then have full access to all video's events.